# Why there is no include link between create and delete use cases

Tags: include, uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have seen on the internet many examples of use cases diagrams (in UML) as this one:

[image]

What I see is that the `delete` use case does not include the `create` use case. Even though I can't imagine deleting a user without creating it.

I wonder why it is still right to not use the include ? And I wonder when should I use it and when to not use it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is `Delete-User - - <<include>> - -> Create-User` that means during the execution of the UC *Delete-User* the UC *Create-User* is also executed, and of course that has no sense.

The expected behavior can be :

- *Delete-User* has the prerequisite *Create-User* was successfully executed for the same user and *Delete-User* was not already executed successfully for the same user (after the last *Create-User* then)
- or *Delete-User* can be executed without prerequisite but if the user does not exist (*Create-User* was not executed successfully for the same user, or *Delete-User* was already executed for the same user after the last creation or the user) this is an error case

Comment: `error case` means it's a certain flow of execution in the UC's course of events. So that's some behavior you don't show on the UC level itself.

Comment: It still unclear, I think I see what you are trying to tell me but I don't see clear. What I understood is that it has no sense to execute the create whenever we want to delete. However, we need to create that user before we can delete it.

Comment: @celia yes, *before* , not *during*, this is why there is no include. For the rest I cannot decide myself what the UC delete-user does because I am not the author of the diagram you give and the textual description of the UCs is not given, I can just give possibilities and this is what I did in my answer. Do you understand (may be also thank to the other answer) ?

Comment: Ahh ok I see, so in the diagram we speak about what is executed _during_ not before. But, in the textual description, we can give more details about the prerequisite. Right ?

Comment: sure if there are prerequisite etc that must be described in the textual description, an UC cannot be just an ellipse in a diagram, like a book is not reduced to its table of content / chapter titles

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, have a super great day.

Answer (score 3):

[Bruno's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63586445/3723423) already explains why it's not a good idea to include `Create` into `Delete`, and what alternatives may be used to express the relation that you explained between the two use-cases.

But in case it helps, here another angle:

- A use-case diagram does not represent a logical sequence of activities.
- A use-case only represents a **goal** for an actor that motivates his/her interaction with the system **independently** of the other use-cases and the system's history.  So, the simple fact that a sysAdmin may want at a moment in time to delete a `User` is sufficient for the use-case `Delete` to exist on its own.
- `include` shows that a goal may include some other goals of interest for the user. Inclusion is **not for functional decomposition** where you'd break down what needs to be done in all the details. It's not either to show the sequential dependency. So for `Delete`, you shall not include what happens before, because happens-before is sequentiality.  Inclusion only highlight some relevant sub-goals that are meaningful for the user and that the user always want to achieve when aiming at the larger goal.
- finally, a use-case `Delete` may have perfect sense even if the use-case `Create` was never performed by any actor, for example because:

  - the new system took over a legacy database with all its past account, and the first thing that the SysAdmin will do in the new system, will be to clean-up the already existing old unused accounts before creating new ones.
  - the SysAdmin wants to `Delete` an account but finds out only during the interaction that the account didn't exist,  was misspelled, or was already deleted. These possibilities are all be alternate flows that you would describe in the narrative of the the same use-case.
  - or if not `Create` use-case would be foreseen, because the user creation would be  done automatically in the background (e.g. based on an SSO), without the actors being involved at all.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer it is even detailed and supports what I have understood from  the comment before. However, how should I understand the include (order --include--> login). The user goal is to order not to login and he won't login while he orders.

Comment: @celia The login is not really a user goal. It’s more a constraint for being identified for doing some things. This being said, even if would be a goal, the inclusion would mean that every time you’d order, you’d also do a login (which is certainly not true if you do two orders in a same login connection).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot !! just a last question, if I do (Grant access -- include --> select user). To mean that every time I grant access I select the targeted user. It is still correct ?

Comment: @celia yes, it is

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally get it. have a good super day

Comment: @celia Glad that it could help :-) A nice day and plenty of success with your project

Comment: Nice complement of my answer, UV